# How docker volume container (mounted a host directory ) used in compose file version 2

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

In compose file version 1 , my docker-compose.yml is :

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes_from:
      -  mongodata
mongodata:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
       - /home/dbdata/mongodb:/data/db
```

In localhost "/home/dbdata/mongodb" ,i saved some data . And it can be read through  mongo container .

But i don't know how to update to **compose file version 2**. I have updated docker and docker-compose to the latest.

```
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027
OS: ubuntu 15.10
```

> I tried three ways ,but not working.

one : the compose file is :

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes_from:
      -  mongodata
    networks:
      - wfij

  mongodata:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
       - /home/dbdata/mongodb:/data/db

 # this is a spring cloud service , it can read mongo user data
  useraccount:
    image: user-account
    networks:
      - wfij
networks:
  wfij:
    driver: bridge
```

But the spring user-account service can't read the mongo data .

> Another method: the compose file

-

```
version: '2'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      -  mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - wfij

  useraccount:
    image: user-account
    networks:
      - wfij


networks:
  wfij:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    volumes: home/dbdata/mongodb
```

It not works again , the error is :  "**volumes is not supported**" , but if i not set the volume container ,how can i mount the host directory "home/dbdata/mongodb" to the  volume  .

> last , try this :

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      -  mongo-data
voluems:
  - mongo-data: /home/keryhu/dbdata/mongodb:/data/db
```

The error is :

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'mongo-data' must be a mapping not a string.
```

Can help me ?

Comment: Is your host Linux? Or Windows or Mac?

Comment: Maybe the volumes/mongo-data/volumes syntax is not supported? (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver)

Comment: @VonC yes, not supported , don't know how to resolve

Comment: Try `volumes:
  mongo-data: home/dbdata/mongodb` (instead of volumes/xxx/volumes)

Comment: @VonC  whether   `volumes:
    mongo-data: /home/dbdata/mongodb` or `volumes:
    - mongo-data: /home/dbdata/mongodb `   not working ,the error is : `volume 'mongo-data' must be a mapping not a string`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104864/discussion-between-kery-hu-and-vonc).

Comment: The chat at work is blocked, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes_from:
      -  mongodata
  mongodata:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
       - /home/dbdata/mongodb:/data/db
```

This should work. You don't have to make any changes for host volumes. It's only important for named volumes.

Comment: sorry, according to your suggest，it not works , while running docker-compose , no errors . but spring service can not get the mongo data

Comment: Then there must be some configuration issue with spring. Can you include the spring error?